# Is it possible to append multiple objects via Java's ObjectOutputStream in a string format?

Tags: java, object, objectoutputstream

My server communicates to the client by Strings, such as 
in server,

```
String message = "I am new at this.";
send("Y" + message);
```

and in client,

```
if (messageReceived.startsWith("Y"){
System.out.println(messageThatServerSentWithoutTheY);
}
```

But suppose I have a HashTable allPotentialWords, and an Array wordlist I want to put through. How is it possible that

```
send("#" + wordlist + "~" +  allPotentialWords);
```

can be isolated, extracted, and used by

```
if (messageReceived.startsWith("#"){
...
}
```

in the Client by having its own variables which are, too, called wordlist and allPotentialWords? I get this is an "Object"OutputStream, but I just cannot think of a way to extract this. It's a string I'm looking at! Is the String that represents the Object itself stored somewhere in memory, which, when the string accessed, brings out the Object when it is properly cast-ed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Why? Just send the individual objects. That's what object streams are for, and that's what they're good at. Don't give yourself a parsing problem unnecessarily.

Comment: Well, the problem here is that the ObjectOutputStream and InputOutputStream depend entirely on the string communication of 
"@" + ... 
 or  "&" + ... or .... and so on, 
which means there are many, many different "codes" which tell the input stream the proper course of action for the thing sent. I need a way to put in several objects into one code in the format of a "code" to start the string off because there is no other way for me to extract an object alone. I can't just say "if (input != null)" because NO other input that it receives is null.

Comment: So send "@", "&", etc, as separate strings. Don't give yourself the additional problem of separaring the tokens. Actually you should consider sending yourself executable objects and executing them instead of having to make any decisions at the receiver. `Runnable` is a good example.